# Compiling GCC keeps running out of memory

Tags: gcc, cross-platform, ram

I'm trying to compile the GCC toolchain for the c-sky architecture(built to run on x86_64), which is all going fine except that I keep running out of memory. Memory usage keeps going up until both my swap and ram are maxed out. I have 54GB of swap, and 8GB of ram. I though, that should do. But it still crashes. So my question is, does GCC really need that much ram to compile? As it's trying to use more than 60GB of ram/swap! Is there something I can do to make it use less ram?

These are the last 20 lines it says when it crashes because of memory btw:

```
onfigure: WARNING: decimal float is not supported for this target, ignored
mkdir big/ck807/soft-fp
configure: WARNING: decimal float is not supported for this target, ignored
mkdir big/ck807/hard-fp
configure: WARNING: decimal float is not supported for this target, ignored
In file included from ../../.././gcc/tm.h:33:0,
                 from /home/tim/Downloads/toolchain-build-master/toolchain/source//gcc/libgcc/libgcc2.c:29:
/home/tim/Downloads/toolchain-build-master/toolchain/source//gcc/libgcc/libgcc2.c: In function '__clear_cache':
/home/tim/Downloads/toolchain-build-master/toolchain/source//gcc/libgcc/../gcc/config/csky/csky-abiv2-linux-elf.h:124:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'cacheflush' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   cacheflush (BEG, END-BEG, 3)
   ^
/home/tim/Downloads/toolchain-build-master/toolchain/source//gcc/libgcc/libgcc2.c:2131:3: note: in expansion of macro 'CLEAR_INSN_CACHE'
   CLEAR_INSN_CACHE (beg, end);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
xgcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
make[4]: *** [Makefile:467: _mulvdi3.o] Error 4
make[3]: *** [Makefile:1161: multi-do] Error 1
make[2]: *** [Makefile:120: all-multi] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:11036: all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:858: all] Error 2

<-- end error output

exec command: export PATH=/home/tim/Downloads/toolchain-build-master/toolchain/install-csky-linux-gnuabiv2-glibc/bin/:$PATH;rm -rf ./* && /home/tim/Downloads/toolchain-build-master/toolchain/source//gcc/configure --target=csky-linux-gnuabiv2 --enable-shared       --with-sysroot=/home/tim/Downloads/toolchain-build-master/toolchain/install-csky-linux-gnuabiv2-glibc/csky-linux-gnuabiv2/libc/ --enable-languages=c    --disable-threads --disable-libssp --disable-libgomp --disable-libmudflap   --disable-libquadmath --disable-libatomic --disable-nls --without-headers --with-newlib  --prefix=/home/tim/Downloads/toolchain-build-master/toolchain/install-csky-linux-gnuabiv2-glibc/ && make && make install
```

It always crashes when out of memory. Could this be a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: When a program tells me "please submit a bug report", I'm generally inclined to believe that there is a bug.  At minimum, the program should not tell me that if there isn't otherwise any bug.  I'm generally inclined in favor of following instructions in such cases.

Comment: More specifically, however, I'd consider it a bug that compilation uses in excess of 50GB of virtual memory.  It's unclear what component is buggy and what the nature of the bug might be, but yes, it looks like a bug.

Comment: In what kind of environment are you building it (what does `uname -a` say?), and with which GCC version? Have you tried it with a different version?